# Changing TextView Opacity in Android

Tags: android, textview, opacity, seekbar

So I'm trying to dynamically change the opacity of a `TextView` in my android app. I have a `seekbar` and as I slide the thumb to the right, the `TextView` I have layered under it should start becoming transparent. When the thumb reaches about half way across the `seekbar`, the text should be completely transparent. I'm trying to use the `setAlpha(float)` method inherited from View on my `TextView`, but Eclipse is telling me `setAlpha()` is undefined for the type `TextView`. Am I calling the method in the wrong way? Or is there another way to change the opacity?

Here's my code (`classicText` is the `TextView`, `gameSelector` is the `seekbar`):

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch){
    classicText.setAlpha(gameSelector.getProgress());
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

you can set the alpha like this

```
int alpha = 0;
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1)).setTextColor(Color.argb(alpha, 255, 0, 0));
```

as the alpha you getting from the seekbar that will be set into the text color

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

**1.** Create class **AlphaTextView.class**:

```
public class AlphaTextView extends TextView {

  public AlphaTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public AlphaTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public AlphaTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onSetAlpha(int alpha) 
  {
    setTextColor(getTextColors().withAlpha(alpha));
    setHintTextColor(getHintTextColors().withAlpha(alpha));
    setLinkTextColor(getLinkTextColors().withAlpha(alpha));
    getBackground().setAlpha(alpha);
    return true;
  }    
}
```

**2.** Add this instead of using TextView to create a textview in your xml:

```
...
   <!--use complete path to AlphaTextView in following tag-->
   <com.xxx.xxx.xxx.AlphaTextView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="sample alpha textview"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:id="@+id/at"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:background="#88FF88"
        />
...
```

**3.** Now you can use this textview in your activity like:

```
at=(AlphaTextView)findViewById(R.id.at);

at.onSetAlpha(255); // To make textview 100% opaque
at.onSetAlpha(0); //To make textview completely transperent
```

Comment: I used a variation of this to change the text alpha without also changing the background alpha, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Now there is a Attribute on XML  as

android:alpha="0.5"

to change the Opacity  through the Layout

Answer (score 6):

change method to following

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch)
{
    classicText.setAlpha((float)(gameSelector.getProgress())/(float)(seekBar.getMax()));
}
```

Comment: this is not working AFAIK. i have tried it..TextView does not have method named setAlpha().check it before answering!

Comment: check method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)

Comment: This is correct reference but you would not be able to use such method for textview or view in your eclipse directly.please check yourself.instead,you need to customize textview and then to use that class in your app.

Comment: I will, when I would get some time, but if it is case, it may be due to TextView has an additional property, so changes in textview itself might not get effect, in this case, we need to set text color, by getting rgb and alpha component and set new alpha in the setTextColor method.

Comment: Yes...Thats true! but after all,we need to use custom class for the same to make the code and approach easier!

Answer (score 3):

It may be late but if anyone is looking for this now, all you have to do is:

```
textView.setAlpha();
```

in brackets enter number between 0 and 1

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a **simple** way to set alpha or opacity programmatically for TextView.
By using function *withAlpha* after getTextColors from textView.

```
// alpha value between 0..255
// 0 for transparent
classicText.setTextColor(classicText.textColors.withAlpha(100))
```

Comment: This is an excellent and concise solution. It does not rely on changing the alpha of the view itself, which also affects any background or compound drawable you might have set on the TextView. Also it does not rely on `setTextColor(int)` which only sets a single color.

Instead this uses the `ColorStateList` you may already have applied to the TextView and directly adjusts the alpha channel for ALL the stateful colors it may have. No need to make a separate ColorStateList, just reuse the same one!

Comment: Thanks bro @TonyChan, your explaination is good, clear and easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

**View.setAlpha (float xxx);**

range of xxx - 0 - 255, 0 being transparent and 255 being opaque.

```
int progress = gameSelector.getProgress();
int maxProgress = gameSelector.getMax();
float opacity = (progress / maxProgress)*255;
classicText.setAlpha(opacity);
```